# Dejar seleccionado la opcion del formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Con .php  y javascript como podría dejar seleccionado la opción que seleccionó el usuario en un formulario, tras darle al boton de input para procesar los campos?

Se obtener el valor que seleccionó, pero no se como llegar al option y  hacerle setAttribute selected selected

```html
    <select id="id_of_select">
            <option></option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
            <option value="4">four</option>
        </select>

        <button id="btn">Show selected</button>

<script>

 function show_selected() {
            var selector = document.getElementById('selectedIMon1');
            var value = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
 var index = selector[selector.selectedIndex].index;
              
 alert(value);
  
        }

       document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', show_selected);
 
        ;
</script>
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagino que lo que buscas es igualar el indice seleccionado en un *select*, en tu caso **selectedIMon1**, con otro, **id_of_select**. Es bastante sencillo, sólo usas la misma propiedad que usaste para obtener el indice, checa este sencillo ejemplo:

```
<select id="select1">
    <option></option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option></option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>
</select>

<button id="btn">Show selected</button>

<script>

function show_selected() {
    var selector1 = document.getElementById('select1');
    var selector2 = document.getElementById('select2');          

    selector2.selectedIndex = selector1.selectedIndex;

}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', show_selected);
</script>
```

Como ves solo igualo la propiedad **.selectedIndex** del selector al indice que quiero dejar, en este caso el indice de mi primer selector *select1*.

Comment: Me expliqué mal, y no cambie el id "selectedIMon1" por  "id_of_select", pido disculpas, lo que quiero conseguir es que se la opcion seleccionada,  aplicarle un setAttribute  selected, por que lo estoy haciendo con php y no se queda  seleccionada la opcion que marcó, es por método post y queria hacer que tras darle al boton ( input) en el select quede reflejado el que marcó y no la primera. no se si me explico adecuadamente

Comment: Sería una cosa así?  selector[selector.selectedIndex].setAttribute("selected","selected"); pero esto no me funciona uso esta forma y me aparece la primera opcion como selected

Comment: Ok, si el index llega por POST, bastaría con que guardaras ese valor en  una variable y ya con esto puedes poner la linea selector.selectedIndex = (aquí tu index).

Comment: Debes notar que el index debes acomodarlo en algún input, desde php, para que luego accedas a el mediante javascript.

Comment: Amigo, hago  (de modo prueba ) ( despues seria incrustar el php en "Euro" document.getElementById("Euro").setAttribute("selected","selected"); ya que a cada uno le he puesto un id para cogerlo con el ID, he puesto un alert a ver si funcionaba y funciona solo el tiempo que esta el alert, luego vuelve a recargar la página y se queda como estaba antes, como puedo hacerlo con cookis?

Comment: Debes hacer uso de variables de sesión de php para llevar un registro de lo que el usuario ha seleccionado en su sesión, en donde puedes implementar cookies, te aconsejo que postees esto como una nueva pregunta en el foro, puesto que se aleja del tema de tu pregunta en esta publicación, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis M. de León, haré tus recomendaciones, Un saludo